# VMware Workstation 7 + Backtrack 3 - USB Problem

Tags: vmware-workstation, backtrack

need help.

im trying to crack WEP keys

here the problems,
why my USB wireless adapter stop working when i connect it to VMware+Backtrack 3?

when i disconnect it from VMware+Backtrack 3 (connect to host), it work as normally.

this is some result.

LSUSB :

Bus 1 Device 2: ID 148f:2070 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 1 Device 1: ID 0000:0000 
Bus 2 Device 2: ID 0e0f:0002 
Bus 2 Device 1: ID 0000:0000

IFCONFIG :

eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:D8:45 inet addr:192.168.1.3 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:299 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:276800 (270.3 KiB) TX bytes:50080 (48.9 KiB) Base address:0x2000 Memory:d8920000-d8940000

lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:0 (0.0 b) TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

help please?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is illegal. Modification, gaining entry, or anything of the such on networks other than your own is frowned upon in this community. If your purpose is to "hack" into your neighbors network you simply put a shame to this community if anyone decides to help you. Please take your busines else where, as such illegal activities are not welcomed here.

TL;DR. GTFO

Comment: He never mentioned he was cracking someone elses wifi. Although you can easily infer that, it wasn't explicitly stated.